# How to avoid force type casting view model instance in child view controllers - MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am new to MVVM, am little confused how to avoid typecasting a view model instance in child view controllers. To explain it better am adding the code below.

Now I know that each ViewController is supposed to have a view model and it should be initialized in init or awakeFromNib.So I declared a protocol as

```
public protocol ViewModelCreatorProtocol : class {
    var viewModel : BaseControllerViewModel! {get}
    func createViewModel()
}
```

and my `BaseControllerViewModel` looks like

```
public class BaseControllerViewModel {
    //some variables common to all child class
}
```

Now I have a `BaseViewController` which confirms to this protocol and all other VCs in my case will extend from `BaseViewController`

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController, ViewModelCreatorProtocol {
    var viewModel: BaseControllerViewModel!

    lazy var disposeBag : DisposeBag = {
        return DisposeBag()
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.createViewModel()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func createViewModel() {
        viewModel = BaseControllerViewModel()
    }

    func hookupViewModelObservables() {
        //hookup observables
    }
}
```

As you can see BaseViewController provides some common properties like `disposeBag` to all childViewControllers and also calls `createViewModel` in `awakeFromNib` and ensures that viewModel is always instantiated even before ViewController is loaded. (Lets assume for now that all my viewModels are initialized using a default init and has no param passed to them)

**Issue:**

Now I create a ChildViewController lets say `AudioPlayerViewController`

```
class AudioPlayerViewController: BaseViewController {
    //override createViewModel of parent to pass my ViewController specific view model

    override func createViewModel() {
        self.viewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel()
    }
}
```

And obviously my `AudioPlayerViewModel` extends from `BaseControllerViewModel` as

```
class AudioPlayerViewModel : BaseControllerViewModel {
    var totalDuration : Int = 0
    var timeObserver : Any? = nil
    //some more variables and logics
}
```

Everything works fine, but now If I have to access `totalDuration` in my `AudioPlayerViewController` I have to access it as

```
(self.viewModel as! AudioPlayerViewModel).totalDuration
```

This makes my entire code base in ViewController to be filled with `(self.viewModel as! AudioPlayerViewModel)` which I think is running my code readability.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: My recommendation is to avoid base view controllers and view models. The minimal benefit you get from reusing a few properties or small methods of the base classes is more than offset by the complexity added. Protocols are better, but why you need a ViewModelCreatorProtocol I don't know.

Comment: @mike-taverne : Issue is I am trying to set the rule that each view controller should have its view model initialized even before it gets loaded. So I thought protocol will do the better job here. If I remove the protocol then it becomes a view controller's responsibility to create their view model but because of protocol it will force all child VCs to create a variable named view model and provides an opportunity to provide its own view model instance by overriding createViewModel . Usage of storyboard makes the dynamic injection of view model a difficult job

Comment: and base class's awake from nib implementation ensures all child VC gets a chance to initialize their vie model with instance in awakeFromNib

Comment: How can your view controller possibly know which view model to load at the point awakeFromNib is called? I get that it knows what type of model, but how can it know which instance of that type to create? For example, if your view controller displays the duration of the track being played, how would it possibly know that duration if you haven’t told it what track to play?

Comment: @mike-taverne : I understand what you are saying, you are talking about the empty initialization of viewModel. Thats ok for now as I had already mentioned in my question. I am planning to instantiate a view controller from storyboard and then access its view model property and assign values to all the variables inside view model. I know its not the correct way to do it but that will work for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use generics? So `BaseViewController` will have a generic type that must inherit the `BaseControllerViewModel`. Something like this:

```
public class BaseControllerViewModel {
    required public init() {
        // needed to do T() in view model creation.
    }
}

class BaseViewController<T: BaseControllerViewModel> : UIViewController, ViewModelCreatorProtocol {
    var viewModel: T! // this will change based on the type you pass in subclass

    lazy var disposeBag : DisposeBag = {
        return DisposeBag()
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.createViewModel()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func createViewModel() {
        viewModel = T() // instantiate the view model
    }

    func hookupViewModelObservables() {
        //hookup observables
    }
}
```

And for example the concrete classes will be:

```
class ExampleVcViewModel: BaseControllerViewModel {
    var subclassVar: Int?
}

class EampleVc: BaseViewController<ExampleVcViewModel> {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(viewModel.subclassVar) // no need to cast
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a very neat solution I'll give a try till then +1

Comment: This is better, but still creates an empty model. What is the possible value of that?

Comment: I would change `BaseControllerViewModel` to a protocol maybe but I wouldn't be worried of an empty base model; this could be good for example if a project grows a lot and it will be needed to add some basic functions

Comment: @rico-crescenzio : Am not with my system buddy gimme sometime Ill try n let u know

Comment: Probably you should change something because you have the `ViewModelCreatorProtocol ` but the main idea is this

Comment: I have accepted this answer because its technically correct but comes with a huge issue that I wont be able to use any of the methods that are annotated with `@objc`. You will usually find `@objc` declaration in protocols to make them optional. I have a CollectionViewProtocols which are declared as optional and my child view controllers would seldom override them. Now if I bring in generics I cant use `@objc` notation if I dont use `@objc` notations to protocols methods they cant be overriden. Compiler starts displaying errors. Its a known issue have a look at

Comment: Bug report filed https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4173 explaining @objc should be supported within extensions of generic classes

Comment: I knew this, it's a kind of objc runtime limitation; I still prefer to use this approach and put protocol conformance within the main class than sacrifice generics because in my opinion it helps a lot in big projects.

Answer (score 2):

Remove viewModel from BaseViewController, every view controller should have it's own viewModel, there is no other way

Comment: @lu : Thanks for the response, but then how can I force all VCs to have a viewModel property and initialize it in init or awake from nib? I could make all VCs to confirm to protocol individually but then how can I bring order in when the viewModel will be initialized? Like all VC should have their view model initialized in awakeFromNib. Because am using storyboard injecting viewModel to ViewController is a challenge hence I opted for base class

Answer (score 1):

For this situation i personally use another property that returns appropriate viewModel. So, it could be:

```
var audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel? {
    return viewModel as? AudioPlayerViewModel
}

func createViewModel() {
    viewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel()
}
```

Or you can remove optional in property, because you know that it will be exactly `AudioPlayerViewModel`.

```
var audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel {
    return viewModel as! AudioPlayerViewModel
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) That was precisely my idea wanted to know if thats okay to do it :) hence +1

Comment: What’s the value of creating an empty model?

Comment: Further, unless you can guarantee the model is of the type intended, force casting could crash your application.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, i mentioned about the vm type.